# Direcionar via .htaccess uma query string

Tags: htaccess

Tenho um sistema onde haverá múltiplos usuários. Cada usuário terá seu próprio subdomínio. Ex.:

```
usuario1.sistema.com.br 
usuario2.sistema.com.br
```

Para isso criei os subdiretórios e em cada um deles criei um **.htaccess** fazendo o redirecionamento para o sistema que se encontra na pasta raíz. Vejam:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cliente1.sistema.com.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.cliente1.sistema.com.br$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sistema.com.br/acesso/$1 [P]
```

O problema é que quando ele cria esse redirecionamento para o sistema, não consigo identificar quem é o cliente, ou seja, se é o **cliente1** ou **cliente2**, etc.

Como eu poderia fazer para identificar esse cliente? Não tenho muita experiência com **.htaccess**, mas acredito que eu poderia usar `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` e no arquivo do sistema pegar no **PHP** com  `$_REQUEST`.  Algo como:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}^cliente=cliente1
```

E no PHP:

```
$cliente = $_REQUEST["cliente"];
```

Se essa for a solução, como eu faria para aplicar o `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` no meu **.htaccess**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

montei essa regra:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cliente([0-9]+).sistema.com.br$ http://www.sistema.com.br/acesso/$1 [P]
```

Adicionei ([0-9]+) qualquer numero de 0 até 9 podendo ser um ou mais caracteres, em seguida coloquei ao final de acesso no redirecionamento. O teste está abaixo na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode usar essa ferramenta e melhorar a gosto : 
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Atualização:

Nesse caso Rei bastaria adaptarmos a regra assim :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+).sistema.com.br$ http://www.sistema.com.br/acesso/$1 [P]
```

Ou como você disse na pergunta que queria fazer um **GET** por cliente no php poderia ser:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+).sistema.com.br$ http://www.sistema.com.br/acesso?cliente=$1 [P]
```

Qualquer conjunto de carácteres de a até z minúsculos ou zero até nove podendo conter traços, e o **+** fora do colchetes significa um ou mais caracteres.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que isto te ajude!

Comment: Olá Rafael. Obrigado pela resposta, mas se no caso em vez do nome ser cliente1, cliente2, for o nome real do cliente. Ex.: fernandopessoa.sistema.com.br, carloschagas.sistema.com.br,... Como eu faria? Me desculpe, coloquei cliente1, cliente2, como forma de exemplo.

Comment: A pessoa que deu downvotes na minha resposta, poderia justificar qual o problema?Uma vez que colei o report do teste que comprova o funcionamento!

Comment: Perfeito Rafael. Funcionou! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Não há de que meu Rei!